# package com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations does not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, xstream

I have to build a Java web project to run it locally and adjust some HTML. Unfortunately, after another updating from SVN server the project stopped being buildable.

Here is the log from IntelliJ IDEA:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\java" -Xms256m -Xmx512m
"-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin\m2.conf"
"-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1"
-Didea.launcher.port=7532
"-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3\bin"
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1\boot\classworlds-1.1.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar"
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain
org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher --no-plugin-registry --fail-fast
--strict-checksums --update-snapshots
-f C:\Users\Kat\IdeaProjects\MYROOT\MYPROJECT\pom.xml install
+ Enabling strict checksum verification on all artifact downloads.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MYPROJECT Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 20 source files to C:\Users\Kat\IdeaProjects\MYROOT\MYPROJECT\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

C:\Users\Kat\IdeaProjects\MYROOT\MYPROJECT\src\main\java\MYPROJECT\dto\BillDto.java:
10,43] error: package com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations does not exist
```

What I have tried:

1. Removed reference to XStream library in IDEA ('Project Structure'->'Libraries'), went offline/online, let Maven to update missing XStream.
2. Directly replaced the .jar and .pom files in the Maven repository (they were recreated during p.1) with the ones, downloaded from XStream website.

Both to no avail. I'm a newbie in Java world, and have no ideas what to do next.

BTW, IDEA sees the XStream classes and lets navigate thru them.

Regards,

Comment: Is it possible the dependency is declared with the incorrect scope? E.g. listed as `test` scope, whereas you now use it in your non-test code? That often fools IDEs, which tend to treat all dependencies as equal. Maven from the command line won't be forgiving, however.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven integration in IntelliJ, then you shouldn't be using the "Project Structure" -> "Libraries" dialog.  IntelliJ will configure those libraries automatically by reading the pom.xml file of your module.

See: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-projects-tool-window.html

and

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-importing.html

You should also verify that the XStream dependencies are still in the pom.xml